# How can I see properties of hidden label?

Tags: vb.net

I am reworded the above question.

Let's say I am using 20 toolbox buttons and or labels or whatever on a VB window app form, and I have changed the default colors, size, and so on. Is there a way to view in code or design view all the properties and values that have been changed **for any one tool (object)** in a pop-up window.

In other words instead of having to go to properties and scroll, I push a hot key and magic! In one small pop-up window, I can see the changes for **btnone**, or **lblTwo** and or even better, make changes on the fly or go back to default values, or change to new values. Like an Xray format tool in brackets, or google.

Comment: what do you mean by *seeing properties* here?

Comment: Which properties of label are you talking about?

Comment: are you talking about Intellisence?

Comment: Properties that were changed from their default value are shown in **bold type** in the Properties window.